# Explanation of hosts/IP addresses and ports involved in implementation of jump host (port forwarding) with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, portforwarding

I am trying to set jump host connection with Paramiko.

This is settings that I have in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host jump.csail.mit.edu
  GSSAPIAuthentication yes
  GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
  VerifyHostKeyDNS yes
Host *.csail.mit.edu !jump.csail.mit.edu 128.52.* 128.30.* 128.31.*
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jump.csail.mit.edu
  GSSAPIAuthentication yes
  GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
  GSSAPIKeyExchange yes
```

and it works if I connect from a Terminal.

I also found [this code](https://gist.github.com/tintoy/443c42ea3865680cd624039c4bb46219) for Paramiko jump host connection and I wonder what should I set `jumpbox_public_addr` and `jumpbox_private_addr` based on the above ssh config setting?

```
import os
import paramiko

ssh_key_filename = os.getenv('HOME') + '/.ssh/id_rsa'

jumpbox_public_addr = '168.128.52.199'
jumpbox_private_addr = '10.0.5.10'
target_addr = '10.0.5.20'

jumpbox=paramiko.SSHClient()
jumpbox.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
jumpbox.connect(jumpbox_public_addr, username='root', key_filename=ssh_key_filename)

jumpbox_transport = jumpbox.get_transport()
src_addr = (jumpbox_private_addr, 22)
dest_addr = (target_addr, 22)
jumpbox_channel = jumpbox_transport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, src_addr)

target=paramiko.SSHClient()
target.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
target.connect(target_addr, username='root', key_filename=ssh_key_filename, sock=jumpbox_channel)

stdin, stdout, stderr = target.exec_command("ifconfig")
for line in stdout.read().split(b'\n'):
  print(str(line))

target.close()
jumpbox.close()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jumpbox_public_addr` is address of your jump server, what should be the `jump.csail.mit.edu`.

`jumpbox_private_addr` (`src_addr` parameter of [`Transport.open_channel`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.open_channel)) is source address of the connection from `jump.csail.mit.edu` to your destination server. In general you do not care about that (as you do not care about a source address and port of most TCP connections). And it definitely should not be the port 22. The following should tell the server to use the defaults:

```
src_addr = ("0.0.0.0", 0)
```